# How to make GPG run pinentry on the correct TTY, not just the most recently opened one?

Tags: ssh, gnupg

I have `export GPG_TTY=$(tty); gpg-connect-agent updatestartuptty /bye;` in my `.profile` so that GPG knows which tty to use when running pinentry.

The issue is that this causes pinentry to start on the *most recently opened pty* as opposed to what I want, which is the pty that cause pinentry to run.

What's the solution to this?  I'm running gpg-agent as an ssh-agent too.

Related, occasionally when I start an action requiring pinentry, absolutely nothing happens - pinentry won't run on any pty, even the most recently opened one.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The agent is accepts connections on a local socket. When it accepts a connection, it can't find out, with which tty the requesting program is connected, of whether it is connected to a tty at all. So it has to choose an input source by other criteria.

In the case where you don't see anything happen, it probably has selected a tty that is already closed or otherwise unavailable.